# Python socketserver - interaction with threading.Lock()?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I have used the SocketServer module to create a small server. It basically works, but I have some questions regarding multiple clients accesing the server simultaneously:

1. When using the absolutely basic TCP SocketServer, i.e. without ThreadingMixin or ForkingMixin - what happens when a second client tries to connect to the server before it is complete serving the first client; will the second connection be dropped - or will the second client block?
2. I have tried adding the ThreadingMixin. In that case I need to protect a certain code block in the server code with a lock

```
lock = threading.Lock()
with lock:
   # Do stuff here ...
   # ...

# Continue in unlocked scope.
```

but the lock is seemingly ignored - and the whole thing crashes. Instead of the with I have also tried using lock.aquire() & lock.release() - then it seems to block unconditionally on lock.aquire(). So to me it seems the ThreadingMixin does not play very nicely with threading.Lock()?

Edit: Dan's comment about using the same lock is probably key to my locking problems; my current handler code looks like this:

```
class MyThreadedHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

   def handle(self):
      lock = threading.Lock()     <-- Each thread a separate lock?!
      with lock:
          # Do serial stuff
      # Continue parallell processing.
```

So - I guess each thread will lock it's personal lock - not very much point!

Comment: For question #2, can you show us a small example that we can run that will demonstrate the problem you see? There should be no problems creating your own lock and locking on it — it shouldn't be ignored, nor should it crash your program. (By crash, do you mean there was an exception?) Stick to `with lock` unless you are doing something special that needs `acquire()` or `release()`. Don't forget to lock on the same lock (not two or more different locks created by the same line of code!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you call `serve_forever` on a `BaseServer`, the thread is dedicated to handling events for the server. Incoming connections and data wait in the socket queue until the thread has free time to grab them. So, new connections and data will wait until your current handler returns. If you have a handler that blocks, all incoming connections and data will wait until it completes.

There is a modest limit to the number of connections you can have pending. Once that limit is exceeded, a TCP stack will typically send a RESET to tell the other side to go away. You can change the value by overriding `server_activate` and calling listen with a larger value:

```
def server_activate(self):
    socket.listen(32)
```

Modest is not necessarily bad - it keeps your server from being overwhelmed.

There is also a limit to the amount of data the socket will queue, but its much more gentle about it. It simply informs the other side that its receive window is full and would it please just shut up for awhile.

*EDIT*
2. The problem with the lock.... locks should be associated with the resource (typically data but maybe an I/O port or even a write to a file to make sure that lines don't interleave) that needs protection, not the thread doing the execution. You have to be careful if you have multiple locks... deadlocks are easy write!

Comment: Thanks a lot; in this case I have written the small & simple client myself in Python. Will the TCP RESET be handled transparently by the operating system, or is that something I would have to support manually in the client?

Comment: @user422005 - its done automatically by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question #1, when you use a server (bound and listening) socket synchronously, and without threading or forking, new connections are queued. They wait until the server gets around to handling them.

When [`listen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) is called on a socket, the argument is the length of this queue of connections waiting for [`accept()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept) to be called, which returns them one by one.

If your `ServerSocket` isn't handling the connections in parallel (with threads or processes), then concurrent connections have to wait. If there are too many concurrent connections, it appears they will be dropped.